# DefaultDirName of an application with changed name in Innosetup 

Tags: registry, guid, inno-setup

I am trying to change the name of my application, but keeping the same GUID. 
So let's say earlier my application name was 'abc' and my Setup section looked like

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf}\abc
DefaultGroupName=abc
```

Now, changing the name of my application to 'xyz', my Setup section looks like

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf}\xyz
DefaultGroupName=xyz
```

I have the logic to detect if abc is installed by checking registry -

```
 SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AppId}_is1
```

and I manually stop the application, delete files, registry entries (I dont call the uninstaller, since I need to avoid a service from being stopped).

Now when I do a fresh install of 'xyz', the destination dir in 'Select Destination Location page' is rightfully "Program Files\xyz", but if abc is previously installed and I try to install xyz on top of it, default directory points to "Program Files\abc". Same goes for group name.

How can I enforce the installation to always pick up the DirName as xyz. Do I need to change the GUID for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set UsePreviousAppDir to No.  This will prevent an install from picking up the previous install directory and should send it to the new directory.

Comment: But will break/create clone installs if the use specifies their own folder on one install.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is to keep the same directory if it's already installed.
This will reduce the surprise to users when custom shortcuts or data locations no longer work. This will also use the new product name for new installs.

If it really is a different version, then it should be able to be installed side by side, and have a new app ID.

Comment: very good point! But I do intend to change the name and let my users know!